# Tsar Bomba Red Forest

Tags: environment, post-apocalypse, weapon-mass-destruction, radiation, nuclear-weapons

Since 1986, a thousand square miles of eastern Europe is off-limits to average people.  That is because of the nuclear accident at Chernobyl.  Ironically, the fact that people aren't allowed in the Chernobyl Exclusion Zone is what turns the zone into a sanctuary for wildlife, most notably in the Red Forest:

[image]

One of the Red Forest's immediate concerns is that when the reactor failed, it contaminated the soil, water and air with 20 times as much radioactive material as the bombings of Hiroshima and Nagasaki.

In this alternate scenario, there is a different Red Forest, caused not by the meltdown of a nuclear power plant, but by the nearby explosion of a nuclear explosion.  As the title suggests, we will be using the Tsar Bomba for a demonstration, for there was no greater nuclear bomb in human history.  The explosion had a blast yield of 50 megatons of dynamite, almost ***2400 times*** the size of the explosion that destroyed Nagasaki and ***more than 3,000 times*** the size of the one that destroyed Hiroshima!  And to make matters worse, there were plans for a Tsar Bomba big enough to blast off ***100 megatons*** of TNT!

Let's say that was exactly what happened--a 100-megaton explosion annihilated a city.  A Red Forest soon sprouted from the barren, radioactive crater.  Animals that were endangered elsewhere are now abundant in this one spot.  Compared to the Red Forest of Chernobyl, how much radiation from the explosion would the trees of this Red Forest store?

Comment: In which conditions did the bomb explode? The tsar bomb was one of the cleanest explosions with respect to their energy, because it exploded mid air

Comment: High yield thermonuclear explosive devices generally produce very low amount of radioactive pollution relative to their yield. There's added complexity here, that should RDS-220 had been detonated with uranium tamper instead of lead, it would have produced many times the fallout. But either way it is not comparable to fission reactor meltdown.

Comment: So, this is quite a difficult question to answer, principally because the type of fallout from a nuclear bomb is _very_ different from the type of fallout from a nuclear reactor. The latter has far more long lived isotopes, making the fallout less immediately deadly but longer lasting. I think that if you wanted to exclude people from an area for a long period, you'd need to use a salted bomb to deliberately generate large amounts of longer-lived radioactive isotopes.

Comment: Please clarify at least the meaning of *"how much radiation would this area store"*. I don't immediately see a meaning for "stored radiation". And you *might* have noticed that Hiroshima and Nagasaki are large thriving cities, with no exclusion zones whatsoever.

Comment: @AlexP, There aren't many people who know the difference between "radiation" and "radioactivity." If we take "radioactivity" to be a lazy synonym for "radioactive contamination," then yeah, it can persist in the environment. And if the average layman thinks that "radiation" means the same thing, then... there you are!

Comment: @AlexP  Stored radiation, as in radiation stored in the soil.

Comment: Radiation (alpha particles, electrons, or gamma photons) cannot be "stored". It hits, does its effects, and then it's gone. You probably mean radioactive material. Nuclear bombs don't produce that much of that, for the reason that they are *designed* to produce as little long lasting damage as possible; nobody wants to conquer a wasteland. Even the [Bikini Atoll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bikini_Atoll), where the U.S.A. detonated 23 rather primitive nuclear devices from 1946 to 1958, is already in a state where it could be made safe for human occupation if so desired.

Comment: You're halfway there.  @AlexP is correct, radiation isn't stored. Particulate fallout could be absorbed into the trees - possibly - but you're also asking for a comparison to the amount of (presumably fallout) that has been absorbed by the existing Red Forest.  Can you point us to any data that describes how much that forest "stored?"  (And, for the record, this seems to be a lengthy way of asking, "how much fallout can a pine tree absorb from contaminated soil?" and it might not be answerable w/o detailed fallout stats.)

Comment: we can answer the 'double tsar bomba - what happens in the destroyed city' - question, or the 'double tsar bomba but with red-forest like contamination' question. which is it?